# Can you add margins for logos in LaTeX, that are in page corners?

Tags: templates, latex, margin

I am currently working on a LaTeX template and I added a logo to my top-right corner, which appears on every page. Works fine.

Is it possible to add a left and top margin, so that the logo does not stick to the side edges?

I am not an LaTeX-pro obviously, so if someone could give me a hint that would be great.

That's what I got so far:

\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
   \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{#1}}}

And after \begin{document} :

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageUpperRight{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo.jpg}}}}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

got it working with the help of the 'background package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background). I think its quite intuitive.

```
\newcommand\BackGroundImage[1]{%
\BgThispage
\backgroundsetup{
pages=all,scale=1,angle=0,position={current page.north}, hshift=5cm, 
vshift=-2.5cm, opacity=1,
contents={%
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#1}
}}}
```

And after \begin{document}:

```
\BackGroundImage{logo}
```